# H2 Database: Get rows from subquery as array

Tags: java, sql, arrays, h2

I have a query which works fine with PostgreSQL, and I need to use it on H2Database.

Important for the tables is basically only an `id integer` field.

The example-query on PostgreSQL with the result is here:

```
select id, 
array_to_string(
    array(select id from table1)
,',') 
from table2
order by id
```

Result:

```
id | array_to_string
2  | 1,3,4,5,2
3  | 1,3,4,5,2
4  | 1,3,4,5,2
6  | 1,3,4,5,2
7  | 1,3,4,5,2
8  | 1,3,4,5,2
9  | 1,3,4,5,2
10 | 1,3,4,5,2
```

For H2, I implemented the user-defined functions `array_to_string` and `array` as follows:

```
public class H2Functions {

    public static String arrayToString(final Object[] array, final String separator) {
        return StringUtils.join(array, separator);
    }

    public static Object array(final Object row) {
        return "???";
    }

}
```

The problem is that I can not implement `array` as I don't know what it get's passed.

The query fails with:

```
Scalar subquery contains more than one row;
```

How can I convince H2 to return something which `array` can work with ?

Comment: Unrelated, but: retrieving ***all*** ids from `table1` for _each_ row of `table2` seems very strange to me. Are you sure you do not want a co-related sub-query? Or even a proper join and `group by` between those tables?

Comment: The query is just an example query, in my application there are clauses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't really want the rows as an array, you want them as a comma separated list. And `array_to_string( array(select id from table1),',')` is needlessly complicated in Postgres to begin with. It can be simplified to

```
select id, 
       (select string_agg(id::text, ',') from table1) as id_list
from table2
order by id
```

And this makes clear that you can simply use H2's `group_concat()` which is the equivalent to Postgres' `string_agg()`:

```
select id, 
       (select group_concat(id separator ',') from table1) as id_list
from table2
order by id
```

Answer (score 1):

Since 1.4.197 H2 vervion  also aggregate the value into an array function ARRAY_AGG is available.
See https://www.h2database.com/html/functions-aggregate.html#array_agg